# php cookie secure javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

I am using `html` and `javascript` for client, `php` for server. Each user, after signing up, will have a `userID` generated by server, and stored in database.
In server I am using `setcookie` so that user don't have to log in every time he goes to another page.

1. My first question is, should I just store the `userID` in the user's cookie for validation? How secure is that?
2. My second question is how do I check for cookie every time a user open a page. Do I make a 'invisible' ajax call (sending its cookie by using `getCookie("userID")` in javascript) to server every time user open a page?

Ever since I finished school, I never know if I am doing things the right way, or if my codes are crap. How do you guys determine if your code is the 'right' way to do it, or is it just base purely on experience?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: are you suggesting that I should use session instead?

Comment: `How do you guys determine if your code is the 'right' way to do it, or is it just base purely on experience?` -- yes, experience has a lot to do with it. Even the best coders started out writing bad code. But you might find sites like http://www.phptherightway.com could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it would not be secure at all - cookies can be set and modified by the user.
2. If you're using PHP (I think you are as there's a tag "PHP"), you should use SESSIONS.

Check the documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Quick example:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']);
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 123;
```

On first request it would print something like `null`, on other request - `123`. It works by generating random value and setting to cookie, that is not easy to guess, then stores all session data to files or other storage by that generated key.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, but I have one more question. The reason why I wanted to use cookie is so that user can close browser and open browser and still be logged in. A lot of website does that, how do a typical website manage that?

Comment: Then you still generate random string, which is not easily guessed, and store that info to database or other store. When user comes with this cookie, you delete (or disable) this value in database and automatically log the user in.